# How to create input form where can be added styled text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create input form as on mockup image, where pressing on green button will add text with green dashed borders. I tried with textarea, but in textarea tag not possible to insert html.

[image: mockup]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Comment: @MisterJojo that was a really cool read, never knew about that attribute! Great share!